# differences between different types of broadcasts in android

Tags: android

I am a little confused with the documentation regarding the different types of sending broadcasts in Android. For example, there is `sendStickyBroadcast()`, `sendBroadcast()`, `sendOrderedBroadcast()` and `sendStickyOrderedBroadcast()`.

What is the difference between a sticky, normal and ordered broadcast?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can compare a sticky broadcast with a sticky note. Someone posts it and you can read when you pass by/your application starts - regardless of when it was posted.

An ordered broadcast is like passing a note - it passes from person/application to person/application. Anywhere in the chain the recipient can elect to cancel the broadcast preventing the rest of the chain from seeing it.

A normal broadcast.. well, just sends to everyone that's allowed & registered to listen to it.

There's a variation of broadcasts that only allow receivers registered **in a running application** to listen to them - i.e. a receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml will **not** trigger for these Intents.

**An update regarding [sendStickyBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#sendStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent)):**

> This method was deprecated in API level 21. Sticky broadcasts should
>   not be used. They provide no security (anyone can access them), no
>   protection (anyone can modify them), and many other problems. The
>   recommended pattern is to use a non-sticky broadcast to report that
>   something has changed, with another mechanism for apps to retrieve the
>   current value whenever desired.

[*Source*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#sendStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent))